# How to exit a sourced R script

Tags: r

Is there a function to exit the current R script, but *not* exit the whole execution?

I mean, in a situation like this:

```
for (i in ...) { 
    ...
    source("model.R")
}
```

In file `model.R`, I need an `exit` function that would end the exection of the `model.R`:

```
...
exit 
...
```

So `stop` and `stopifnot` are out of question...

Comment: Put your code in a function and call `return` or `invisible` when you want to break out of the function call.

Comment: Oh my, it seems there is no simple (unhacky) solution that wouldn't require big changes in code. R is sometimes pain to use - no exit, no goto...

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich maybe easier for me would be to create a loop and then break from it. Because code in functions sometimes works differently (global variables etc). Thank you for inspiring me to this idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that by far the easiest solution is to wrap the *whole* code in the sourced script into a loop and then break from it:

`model.R` (sourced script):

```
repeat {

...
break # this will exit the sourced script
...

break # just to prevent infinite loop in case the above break is removed
}
```

Thanks Joshua Ulrich for inspiration (he proposed to use a function).

Answer (score 7):

It seems unusual to me to use source in this way -- it populates the environment from which it's run with whatever symbols it assigns to, so multiple calls to source could easily have unanticipated side effects. Instead I'd follow @JoshuaUlrich's advice and formulate the script as a (reusable, maybe more modular) function. But for what it's worth, create and signal a 'condition' in "model.R"

```
cond = structure(list(message="I'm done"), class=c("exit", "condition"))
signalCondition(cond)
```

and catch when sourcing

```
tryCatch(source("model.R"), exit=function(cond) {
    message("finished because:", conditionMessage(cond))
})
```

Minimize the changes to model.R by defining an `exit()` function

```
exit <- function(message=character(), class="exit") {
    cond <- structure(list(message=message), class=c(class, "condition"))
    signalCondition(cond)
}

for (i in 1:5) {
    ## model.R simply invokes exit() or exit("I'm done") or exit(class="alt")
    ## if tryCatch wanted to handle conditions of class 'alt', too. 
    tryCatch(source("model.R"), exit=message)
}
```

I guess the `invokeRestart()` solution is more straight-forward; the merit of the above being the opportunity to indicate a reason for early exit.

Comment: +1 Thanks, but all this aparatus for a simple exit? R is really pain to use sometimes...

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use `invokeRestart` in your source file, and wrap the call to `source` with `withRestarts`. For example:

```
t <- tempfile()
write(file=t, "
message('source A')
invokeRestart('terminate')
message('source B')
")

for (i in 1:3) {
    message(i)
    if (i == 2)
        withRestarts(source(t), terminate=function() message('terminated'))
}
# 1
# 2
# source A
# terminated
# 3

unlink(t)
```